# Jbo-25089: Too many matching records found. Specify additional criteria to limit the number of records

Tags: performance, oracle-adf

I have a LOV in the UI. Upon clicking it, it shows the values in it. Upon selecting a particular value in that LOV, the error pops up saying that:

```
Too many records found with matching criteria.
```

This happens only for the first value that I am selecting from the LOV. If I select a different value from the LOV again, this error doesn't appear.

The range size of the iterator that this LOV uses is `25`. I have used the preferred tuning settings in the VO to which the LOV belongs. Please help me in understanding why this is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the value of LOV .. it may have redundancy

Answer (score 0):

It occures when there is a duplicate record in viewObject for same attribute, Is there any other record in that VO ?